# New electron BrowserWindow starting at specified ui-router state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, electron

Is it possible to create a new `BrowserWindow` at a specified `ui-router` state? Here's my `main.js`:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron')

let win

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 950, height: 660 })
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => { win = null })

  app.dock.setMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    { label: 'Open at page', click: () => { goToState('page') } }
  ]))
}

let goToState = (state) => {
  if (!win) {
    createWindow()
    // when win is ready, call win.webContents.send('sref', state)
  } else {
    win.webContents.send('sref', state)
  }
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

The `'sref'` event performs a `$state.go(state)` in the rendered process.

What I already tried:

- **Pass the function as callback in `createWindow()`**

  ```
  function createWindow (callback) {

    ...

    if (callback) callback()
  }

  let goToState = (state) => {
    if (!win) {
      createWindow(() => {
        win.webContents.send('sref', state)
      })
    } else {
      win.webContents.send('sref', state)
    }
  }
  ```
- **Use `app.on('web-contents-created')`**

  ```
  let goToState = (state) => {
    if (!win) {
      createWindow()
      app.on('web-content-created', () => {
        win.webContents.send('sref', state)
      })
    } else {
      win.webContents.send('sref', state)
    }
  }
  ```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try just setting the url with the state after the hash:

```
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html#/page`)
```

assuming you have a ui-router state configured with the url:

```
"url":"/page"
```

Comment: Thank you, since state names are equal to their url, this solution it's enough for my app. I've added `stateUrl` as parameter in `createWindow()`.